# Jenkins - Display text from a file in a parametrized build depending on previous choice

Tags: jenkins

Is there any way to display an informative text from a file located in workspace, on a parametrized build step depending on an previous condition (like using active Choice plugin)?

```
        activeChoiceReactiveParam('branch') {
          description('Select the branch you are going to use')
          choiceType('SINGLE_SELECT')
          groovyScript {
            script('["develop", "master"')
            fallbackScript('"Error. No branch to select."')
        }
          filterable(true)
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can pass on text and parameters from one job to another using a **properties** file and inject it as environment variables in your desired job. The [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) lets you do injection of that properties file in the desired job.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Manmohan_singh, but I think that this is not what I am looking for..